# No puedo trabajar con las propiedades text en Atom, aparecen deshabilitadas

Tags: atom-editor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: overline;
  text-indent: inherit;
  text-overflow: inherit;
```

en la imagen se ve: ( puede que sea un package que sea necesario, no me había pasado esto antes)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se ve la imagen

Comment: hola, ahí está la imagen...puede que sea que estoy en una máquina con windows 7 y sea mu vieja?

Comment: el file es `.css` ? porque en la pestaña parece ser un `.cs`, capas sea eso

Comment: Hola @FedericoIannarelli, si fuese eso, sucedería que Atom tomaría la extension del archivo como C#, por lo que no sería su problema (dado que toma correctamente su sintaxis de css y la marca con los colores respectivos de la extensión), además de que en la barra lateral donde ves los archivos aparece correctamente su extensión.

Comment: @GonzaloTorresDelFierro pero, realmente no entiendo tu pregunta, podrías dar una mayor explicación del problema que tienes? gracias.

Comment: sí,  pasa que al usar cualquier propiedad como tex-decoration; text-align; o cualquier propiedad text, estas aparecen en color gris como se ve en la foto del editor, como se puede ver en la  imagen la propiedad background-color:red; aparece con dos colores, indicando que esta propiedad está activa y efectivamente se aplica como estilo sobre la página, esto no ocurre con ninguna propiedad text que necesite usar. y esa es mi duda por que me pasa esto; espero esté mas clara mi duda gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Deberías instalar u observar si tienes descargado los paquetes de `language-css` y `autocomplete-css`, prueba y me dices...

Comment: perfecto, instalaré esos paquetes ahora, te aviso @jecorrales

Comment: paquetes están habilitados, pero no funciona..me parece extraño

Comment: Y ya miraste si los atributos de cada propiedad se visualizan en el navegador, al inspeccionar cada elemento?

Comment: @GonzaloTorresDelFierro tu máquina no debería afectar en nada la funcionalidad de Atom, siempre y cuando Atom guarde correctamente la información contenida en un archivo de x extensión. Por lo que si quieres verificar, abre el archivo en otro editor de texto y si este se visualiza correctamente es porque tu navegador está bloqueando la instrucción que le estás dando, por loque de nuevo inspecciona bien el elemento al que le estás apuntando. Prueba tambien cambiar y crear una clase en vez de apuntar al body de tu página.

Comment: gracias, haré lo que me indicas, por cierto estoy instalando otro editor, para ver que pasa...te comentaré@jecorrales

Answer (score 3):

Me sucedió lo mismo hace algún tiempo.

Atom toma por defecto la extensión de tu archivo (.css .html .php, etc) y así mismo aplica a la sintaxis unos colores preestablecidos.

Si esto no sucede de forma automática, o está como texto plano, puedes cambiarlo de la siguiente manera.

Abajo del todo a la derecha vas a ver la sección donde se especifica el lenguaje a usar y por tanto a marcar (en el ejemplo, plain text)

[image: Paso1]

Haciendo clic sobre esa opción, puedes cambiar el tipo de lenguaje que se va a aplicar en la sintaxis, puedes ver que son varios.

[image: Paso2]

Por último, escoge el que deseas usar (puedes hacer este cambio manualmente las veces que desees). Como recomendación, y en caso de no ser así, deja por defecto **Auto Detect**

[image: Paso3]

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384159/9609518)

---

> **Actualización**

Me quedó vagando tu pregunta en la mente, y me doy cuenta que no había intentado reproducir exactamente tu código CSS en mi editor Atom; para sorpresa mía, ocurre lo mismo que en tu imagen:

[image: Atom]

Esto sucede porque Atom (*por defecto*) resalta en color (*en archivos CSS en este caso*) únicamente las clases, los valores de color (*hexadecimal, RGBA, etc*), los valores de número (`px`, `%` , `.rem`, etc), valores de duración (`s`, `ms`, etc), las pseudo-clases y los pseudo-elementos (`:hover`, `:focus`, `::after`, `::before`, etc) entre otros.

No resalta ni da color a propiedades con valores como `display`, `none`, `relative`, `auto`, `absolute` y muchos más valores de tipo "texto".

Puedes validarlo tú mismo, por ejemplo, viendo en Atom la hoja de estilos de Bootstrap.

Comment: gracias, @Jheyman Mejia, efectivamente verifique lo que indicas, pero sigue apareciendo gris, el auto completado funciona perfecto, pero no se activa la propiedad, esto me está dando dolores de cabeza, casi que reinstalo todo atom para ver que pasa, ahora mi duda es si el sistema operativo que estoy usando tiene algo que ver, por que estoy en windoes 7 con una maquina mas viejita, antes usaba un i5 y no tenia estos problemas

Comment: Valida que tengas actualizado el paquete `grammar-selector`. Está en la sección de Core Packages

Comment: sabes. estuve verificando en el editor chrome, y verifiqué que las instrucciones de body, no estaban aplicadas, y las modifique directamente en la consola, y funciona, ahora también me di cuenta que el documento está bien con su link, y todo, probé otro editor, el notepad ++ y tampoco funcionó,, tal vez sea una estupidez, pero me ha gastado bastante tiempo. ( no se como adjuntar una imagen acá para mostrar mi consola), seguiré intentando @Jheyman Mejia

Comment: @GonzaloTorresDelFierro acabo de actualizar mi respuesta